# Взаимодействие через Popen с вводом и выводом

Tags: python, subprocess

Пытаюсь перехватить ввод/вывод потока выполнения программы (на примере cmd.exe):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

def main():

    proc = Popen(["cmd"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)


    while True:
        a = (proc.stdout.readline())
        if not a: break
        else:
            print a.deco

    proc.stdin.write('ping 192.168.1.1')

    a = (proc.stdout.readlines())

    print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В принципе, у меня получается получить первые строки (кстати почему-то работает только через `proc.stdout.readline`):

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]

но на строке

```
proc.stdin.write('ping 192.168.1.1')
```

Останавливается и ожидает. Пробовал в конце добавлить `chr(13)` - не помогает. Как правильно отправлять данные в поток?

UPDATE:

Получилось записать и прочитать так:

```
cmds = ['echo ok','ping 192.168.1.1\n']

p = Popen(["cmd"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

for cmd in cmds:
    p.stdin.write(cmd + "\n")
p.stdin.close()

print p.stdout.read().decode('cp866')

p.stdin.write('echo next task') # error on closed descriptor
```

Но после того, как p.stdin закрыт, открыть его обратно уже не могу. Делаю вывод, что python не поддерживает постоянное перенаправление ввода вывода с консолей другого приложения. К сожалению, это ставит крест на моей задаче

Comment: Как вы определяете, что останавливается именно на этой строке, а не на readlines?

Comment: @andreymal, потому что любой код после этой строчки не выплняется. Даже обычный print('a'). Ну отладчик до нее доходит и все

Comment: Ну в показанном вами коде `print a` стоит после readlines, и можно предположить, что зависает именно readlines